# how to use selenium with UWP webview

Tags: selenium-webdriver, uwp, selenium-edgedriver

How to do use Selenium to interact/automate with a UWP webview?  I know about winappdriver, but I have a lot of already written code that I built on selenium webDrivers.  Is there a way for me to attach a webDriver instance to Webview in UWP?